# Dynamically Define ReactJS Routes from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have a global JSON configuration that has a variety of configuration data, including route names and the components that I'd like to be rendered for the route. I'd like to dynamically build my routes from this JSON configuration. I'm currently able to dynamically generate the route, however, since the route components are Strings in the JSON file, React doesn't like them and throws the error below. Any suggestions for accomplishing this goal?

```
warning.js:44 Warning: Unknown props `history`, `location`, `params`, `route`, `routeParams`, `routes` on <Dashboard> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see https://f b.me/react-unknown-prop
    in Dashboard
    in RouterContext
    in Router
```

Relevant JSON snippet:

```
{
    "routes" : [
        {
            "route_name"              : "home",
            "path"                   : "/",
            "visible_in_menu"         : true,
            "menu_title"              : "Home",
            "menu_font_awesome_icon"  : "fa fa-home",
            "component"              : "App",
            "child_routes"            : null
        },
        {
            "route_name"              : "analytics",
            "path"                   : "/analytics",
            "visible_in_menu"         : true,
            "menu_title"              : "Analytics",
            "menu_font_awesome_icon"  : "fa fa-bar-chart",
            "component"              : "Dashboard",
            "template"                : null,
            "child_routes" : [
                {
                    "route_name"      : "analytics_daily" ,
                    "path"           : "/daily",
                    "visible_in_menu" : true,
                    "menu_title"      : "Daily",
                    "component"      : "Dashboard"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Code to fetch config and dynamically build the routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import $ from 'jquery';

import App from './App'; 
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import SidebarMenu from './SidebarMenu';

import './index.css';

$.get("/routes_menu_config.json", bootstrapApplication);

function bootstrapApplication(config){

    var dynamicRoutesJSX = buildDynamicRoutes(config);

    // Add dynamic routes to app
    ReactDOM.render((
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        {dynamicRoutesJSX}
      </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));

    // Render sidebar menu
    ReactDOM.render(
        <SidebarMenu />,
        document.getElementById('menu')
    ); 

}

function buildDynamicRoutes(config){

    var routeJSX = [];

    for (let [index, route] of config.routes.entries()) {
      routeJSX.push(<Route path={route.path} components={route.component} key={index}/>);       
    }

    return routeJSX;
}
```

I also tried the plain object instantiation of routes instead of using JSX, but it produces the same error:

```
$.get("/routes_menu_config.json", bootstrapApplication);

function bootstrapApplication(config){

    var dynamicRoutesJSX = buildDynamicRoutes(config);

    // Add dynamic routes to app
    ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={dynamicRoutesJSX} 

    // Render sidebar menu
    ReactDOM.render(
        <SidebarMenu />,
        document.getElementById('menu')
    ); 

}


function buildDynamicRoutes(config){

    var routes = [];

    // Iterate parent routes from config
    for (var i=0; i<config.routes.length; i++) {

        var configParentRouteDefinition = config.routes[i];

        // Create parent route definition
        var parentRouteDefinition = {
            path : configParentRouteDefinition.path,
            component: configParentRouteDefinition.component
        };

        // If there are child routes, add them to the definition
        if(configParentRouteDefinition.child_routes){

            // Track child routes
            var childRoutes = [];

            // Iterate child routes, generate definition
            for(var j=0; j<configParentRouteDefinition.child_routes.length; j++){

                var configChildRouteDefinition = configParentRouteDefinition.child_routes[j]


                var childRouteDefinition = {
                    path : configChildRouteDefinition.path,
                    component: configChildRouteDefinition.component         
                };

                childRoutes.push(childRouteDefinition);
            }

            // Ad the definition to the parent route definition
            parentRouteDefinition["childRoutes"] = childRoutes;

        }

        routes.push(parentRouteDefinition);

    }

    return routes;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a registry of components so that you can look up component references from their name:

```
import App from './App'; 
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';

const componentRegistry = {
    "App": App,
    "Dashboard": Dashboard
}

<Route path={route.path} components={componentRegistry[route.component]} key={index}/>;
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I was hoping there'd be a way to just convert the string to the instantiated component.

Comment: Unfortunately not, a string tells React to render an HTML node, it does not internally keep track of what components exist and so has no way to look them up.

Answer (score 3):

If you use e.g. Webpack it is possible without import all components to have result you want. However you have to pass path to the component rather the component's name. like so:

```
json file:
{"nav": [
{
  "label": "HOME",
  "route": {
    "url": "/",
    "exact": true
  },
  "component": {
    "path": "home",
    "name": "home"
  }
}}
createRoutes() {
    return this.props.data.nav.map((item: any, index: number) => {
        let DynamicComponent = require('../../' + item.component.path + '/' + item.component.name).default;
        return <Route key={index} path={item.route.url}
                      exact={item.route.exact}
                      render={() => (<DynamicComponent key={item.component.name}/>)}/>
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

> App.tsx

```
import routes from "./routes";
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            {routes.data.map((entry) => {return (<Route {...entry}/>)})}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

> router.ts

```
const routes = {data: [
        {
            key: "one",
            path: "/three"

        },
        {
            key: "two",
            path: "/two"
        }
    ]
}

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to complicate things. Use Below method .

React v.18 and router is 6.5.0

```js
import React from 'react';
import Home from  './home.js';
import About from  './about.js';
import Contact from  './contact';
const Navigation = [
    {   
        id : 1,
        name: 'home',
        url : '/',
        element : <Home />,
    },
    {
        id : 2, 
        name: 'About',
        url : '/about',
        element : <About />,
    },
    {
        id : 3, 
        name: 'Contact',
        url : '/contact',
        element : <Contact />,
    },  
];
export default Navigation;

import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Routes, Route}  from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './JSON';
import Home from  './home';
function Paths(){
    let paths = Navigation.map((paths) => (<li key={paths.id}><Link to={paths.url}>{paths.name}</Link></li>));  
    return(<>
        <ul>
            {paths}
        </ul>
    </>);
}
function Routing(){
    const routers = Navigation.map((paths) => 
        <Route key={paths.id} path={paths.url} element = {paths.element}></Route>); 
    return(<>
        <Router>
            <Paths />
            <Routes> 
                {routers}
            </Routes>               
        </Router>
    </>);
}

export default Routing;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```